# why doesnt fastapi return my mongodb objects?

Tags: python, mongodb, rest, postman, fastapi

## So I am trying to make a request on the route:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/testadmins
with the folowing function:

```
@app.get("/testadmins/")
async def get_admins():
    return await get_database()
```

## get_database() is this:

```
async def get_database():
    uri = "(my mongo uri)"
    client = MongoClient(uri, server_api=ServerApi('1'))
    adms = client.test['admins'].find()
    print(adms)
    
    return adms
```

The function should return all the admins in that collection.

if I print the admins to the console they are shown, but the route wont return them.
i get this error:
TypeError('vars() argument must have **dict** attribute')]

I tried adding async await everywhere, i tried wrapping the function in fastApi's json_encodable()
but nothing.

If I try to make the request in Postman it returns 500 ( internal server error ).

what should I do?

( update: i think it has to do with the date and time as it tried only one key at a time multiple times and only those that had a value stored as a datetime.datetime(...) format didnt work.

( __v and _id didnt work either but idk )

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 235, in jsonable_encoder
    data = vars(obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 426, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 84, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 289, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 122, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 20, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 17, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 718, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
    response = await func(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 291, in app
    content = await serialize_response(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 179, in serialize_response
    return jsonable_encoder(response_content)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 209, in jsonable_encoder
    jsonable_encoder(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 238, in jsonable_encoder
    raise ValueError(errors) from e
ValueError: [TypeError("'ObjectId' object is not iterable"), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]
```

Comment: Show the full traceback to that error you're getting. I think your issue is that the objects in `adms` aren't directly encodable as JSON.

Comment: done, i added the traceback

Comment: There you go: `TypeError("'ObjectId' object is not iterable")` – the items returned from your code have object IDs that can't be serialized.

Answer (score 0):

you should modify

```
async def get_database():
    uri = "(my mongo uri)"
    client = MongoClient(uri, server_api=ServerApi('1'))
    adms = []
    cursor = client.test['admins'].find()
    for document in cursor:
        document.pop('ObjectId')
        adms.append(document)
    return adms
```

Comment: aint mentioned it but i tried it, did not work, just tried it again and nothing

Comment: add a new line between "for document in cursor:" and "adms.append(document)"       "document.pop('ObjectId')" retry and tell me result

Comment: didnt even fulfill the request, it timed out

Comment: show me the trackback info

Comment: i get no traceback, the request times out ,thats all

Comment: I realize a problem. How about delete all "async" and transform "await get_database()" to "get_database()"

Answer (score 0):

**I solved the Object Id problem with the following: **

```
document['_id'] = str(document['_id'])
```

I just transformed it into a string and now it works.

also I removed some other function calls, added some params, anyways, here s the whole code:

```
db = MongoClient(uri)

    result = []
    collection = db.test[collection_name].find()

    for document in collection:
        # Convert ObjectId to string
        document['_id'] = str(document['_id'])
        result.append(document)

    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the bson.ObjectID object is not encoded.

I checked with **fastapi version 0.110.0** you can explcitly add econders for particular type.

In the module containing the endpoint, let's say main.py, add:

```
from bson import ObjectId
from fastapi.encoders import ENCODERS_BY_TYPE

ENCODERS_BY_TYPE[ObjectId] = str
```

This specifies to the encoder to transform the bson.ObjectId object class into str

Each time an bson.ObjectId needs to be encoded it will automatically do it